# can't get any event trough Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get public events ith with the word "music" from facebook API, but the API is returning nothing.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)
events = graph.request('/search?q=music&type=event&limit=10000')
```

and the result that I get is:

```
{'data': []}
```

The access token is a user access token and is working for other stuff like find places instead of events.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that´s even possible? did you check out the docs? afaik event search is deprecated.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?I'm trying this too, but no luck yet.

Comment: @gab no, it is deprecated. Anyway, make me know if you figure it out.